# Server Side using C# to access Oracle DB through ODBC datasource failed while C# long datatype mapping to Oracle Number

Tags: c#, oracle, types, odbc

I am writing a WebApi to provide client users to upload files and the file information will saved to Oracle Database through ODBC(32-bit). The WebApi server side language is C#. The filesize datatype in Oracle is Number.
I get the filesize from "new System.IO.FileInfo(fileSavePath).Length" and its datatype is long. Then I pass it by the following codes:

```
String strCmd = "INSERT INTO UPLOAD_FILE (FILENAME, FILETYPE, FILESIZE) Values (:Filename, :Filetype, :Filesize)";
using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(strConn))
{
  using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(strCmd, conn))
  {                    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":Filename", FILE.FILENAME); //FILE is CLASS.
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":Filetype", FILE.FILETYPE);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":Filesize", FILE.FILESIZE);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

And the Insert action fails.
According the two Datatype mapping tables:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/odbc-data-type-mappings

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15817_01/server.111/e10311/apa.htm

I thought it should be no problem.
Even though I changed the codes to:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter
{
   ParameterName = ":Filesize",
   OdbcType = OdbcType.BigInt,
   Value = FILE.FILESIZE
});
```

And set the datatype of the filesize to Number(19,0)...It still faild.

However, if I let the datatype be int or decimal and it works:

```
Convert.ToInt32(FILE.FILESIZE) / Convert.ToDecimal(FILE.FILESIZE)
```

SO my question is why the SQL_BIGINT(ODBC) or long(C#/.Net) can't map to Oracle Number datatype??? Or I miss some conversion processes???

Comment: What is the error message? "it failed" is not very informative.

Comment: Which ODBC driver do you use? The Microsoft or the Oracle one?

Comment: dear Wernfried Domscheit: "it failed" means the file information record wasn't inserted into my UploadFileTable. I would pass the file id (if it succeeded) with other data to client side so the error of the server side is that the return value of file id is null and the error of the client side is 500 (Internal Server Error). Sorry I am not familier with the ODBC or Oracle settings. I just checked ODBC datasource... it shows 32 bits / Oracle in OraDb11g_home1 and I access the DB using sqldeveloper tool.

Comment: `Oracle in OraDb11g_home1` sounds like the ODBC driver from Oracle - which is fine. The Microsoft driver is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle) for ages.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it like this?

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(":Filename", OdbcType.BigInt);
cmd.Parameters[":Filename"].DbType = DbType.Int64;
cmd.Parameters[":Filename"].Value = FILE.FILENAME;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter {
    ParameterName = ":Filename",
    OdbcType = OdbcType.BigInt,
    DbType = DbType.Int64,
    Value = FILE.FILENAME
});
```